# How can I change < values in mean to numeric form?

Tags: r

```
MDL = c(5,.6,.7,.5,3,.5,2,1,2,5)
Mean= c("<5",2,3,4,"<3",6,7,8,9,10)
```

Change all means with "<" to 2/3 MDL

how can i change string to numeric?

Comment: Hi.. do you mean making "<5" and "<3" , the value of 2*mean(MDL)/3 ?

Answer (score 2):

We can create an index with `grep` to match the `<`, then use that index to update the values of 'Mean'

```
i1 <- grepl("<", Mean, fixed = TRUE)
Mean[i1] <-  2/3 * MDL[i1]
Mean <- as.numeric(Mean)
```

EDIT: Based on @RuiBarradas comments

Comment: Actually, `2/3 MDL` should be `2*MDL[i1]/3`.